# JQuery Show More/Less Example

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, toggle, frontend

I want to use Jquery toggle to do Show More/Less attribute. But my click function doesn't work. How can I fix it? Here are my codes below.

```
 <style>
    .morecontent span {
        display: none;
    }
</style>
<script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
        // Configure/customize these variables.
        var showChar = 100;  // How many characters are shown by default
        var ellipsestext = "...";

        $('#seo-content').each(function() {
            var content = $(this).html();        
            if(content.length > showChar) {      
                var c = content.substr(0, showChar);
                var h = content.substr(showChar, content.length - showChar);         
                var html = c + '<span class="moreellipses">' + ellipsestext+ '&nbsp;</span><span class="morecontent"><span>' + h + 
                '</span></span>';        
                $(this).html(html);
            }    
         });

        $("#seo-header").click(function(){
            $(this).parent().prev().toggle();
            $(this).prev().toggle();
            return false;
         });       
    });
</script>
<body>
<div id="seo-header">Click for More</div>
<div id="seo-content">
  Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut      labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.
</div>
```

Comment: `$('#seo-content').each(...)` IDs ***must*** be unique on document context. Are you using duplicate IDs?

Comment: Your "click" handler is written to affect the previous sibling element of the parent of the clicked element, and of the clicked element itself; however, your "content" blocks come **after** the headers.

Comment: I use as class but result didn't change

Comment: Suggestion: use `event.preventDefault()` instead of `return false;` which is BTW **not needed** since you're not operating with (i.e.) anchor elements.

Comment: @Pointy what is your suggestion

Comment: Well for one thing `.next()` instead of `.prev()`, and there's no reason to mess with the parent.

Answer (score 1):

If you just want each element with the class `seo-header` to toggle the next element with the class `seo-content`, this will work

Note that this changes your ids to classes which allows you to give the behaviour to many elements instead of just one

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
       $('.seo-header').click(function(){
          
             $(this).next('.seo-content').toggle();
          
         });
      
       
    });
```

```css
.morecontent {
        display: none;
    }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="seo-header">Click for More</div>
<div class="seo-content morecontent">
  Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut      labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.
</div>
<div class="seo-header">Click for More</div>
<div class="seo-content morecontent">
  Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut      labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.
</div>
<div class="seo-header">Click for More</div>
<div class="seo-content morecontent">
  Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut      labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.
</div>
<div class="seo-header">Click for More</div>
<div class="seo-content morecontent">
  Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut      labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.
</div>
<div class="seo-header">Click for More</div>
<div class="seo-content morecontent">
  Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut      labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.
</div>
```